# Audio redirection over Remote desktop activex

Tags: audio, activex, rdp

Does remote desktop activex from Microsoft support Audio redirection? How about sound redirection from client to the host e.g. Mic to a skype session on the remote computer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the ActiveX control supports all of the options that the RDP client itself does, as far as I can tell. For audio input redirection, see [IMsRdpClientAdvancedSettings7::AudioCaptureRedirectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee338627.aspx).